# ¿Cómo funciona un bucle while True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Quisiera saber cómo funciona un bucle **while True:** en Python 3.

¿Es posible hacerlo cambiando `True` por `False`? En caso de ser posible, ¿Cómo funcionaría?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un ciclo `while` está iterando mientras la expresión que le sigue (condición de salida) sea evaluada como verdadera. Podemos "traducirlo" por:

```
mientras la <expresión> sea verdadera:
    hacer algo
```

Un ejemplo:

```
n = 0
while n <= 5:
    print(n)
    n = n + 1
```

en este caso la condición de salida es que la variable `n` sea mayor de 5, mientras esta condición no se cumpla el ciclo seguirá iterando.

En el caso de `while True` la expresión **siempre** va a ser evaluada como verdadera por definición. Volviendo a nuestra traducción equivaldría a:

```
mientras verdadero sea verdadero:
    hacer algo
```

Por lo que estamos ante un ciclo infinito que iterará hasta el fin de los tiempos (o la CPU entre en combustión...ツ), a no ser que usemos un `break`, `return` (dentro de una función/método) o terminemos el proceso de forma forzada. Lo mismo ocurre con cualquier objeto que sea evaluado como verdadero (`while "a"`, `while 0.1`, `while 1` etc)

En cuanto a `while False`,  es sintaxis válida pero el ciclo no va a iniciarse siquiera ya que su condición de control es falsa de inicio obviamente. Lo mismo ocurre con cualquier objeto que sea evaluado como falso (`while ""`, `while 0`, `while None`, etc)

Comment: Muy buena respuesta, @AJSevilla... Aunque lo del while False parece bastante improbable de usar, al menos en mi caso no veo en que circunstancia pudiera ser aplicable, pero en el mundo de la programación creo que siempre se presentan oportunidades y necesidades para todas las posibilidades que nos ofrece el lenguaje...

Comment: Si quieres que el ciclo se inicie con `False`, podrías usar `while not False`.

Answer (score 5):

La sintáxis de la sentencia `while` es la siguiente:

```
while [expresión]:
    [cuerpo]
```

Es decir, se ejecuta el `[cuerpo]` de la sentencia `while` mientras `[expresión]` siga siendo evaluado como verdadero.

> ¿Cómo funciona un bucle while True: en Python 3?

Como `True` siempre seguirá siendo verdadero hasta el fin de los tiempo podemos deducir que:

```
while True:
    [cuerpo]
```

Es un bucle infinito a menos, obviamente, que exista una condición para terminarlo dentro de su propio cuerpo (usando `break`, por ejemplo):

```
while True:
    # ...
    if [condicion] == False:
        break
```

Si no existiera la condición de terminación, el bucle `while` se ejecutaría de forma indeterminada.

> ¿Es posible hacerlo cambiando True por False, y en tal caso cómo funcionaría?

Si tienes lo siguiente:

```
while False:
    [cuerpo]
```

Simplemente nunca se va a ejecutar ya que `False` nunca será evaluado como verdadero, sin embargo, si estás totalmente decidido a crear un bucle infinito usando `False` en vez de `True` puedes simplemente usar una negación:

```
while not False:
    [cuerpo]
```

Un poco de lógica booleana básica ;-)

Comment: Excelente respuesta @César... ¿Y en que caso sería justificable usar un while not en la sentencia?...parece un poco ilógico, pero supongo que depende de la lógica personal del programador...

Answer (score 2):

Hola pues ya te pusieron muchas respuestas muy completas, pero lo que te voy a responder es cuando es necesario usar el while false.

Si tu pones while False: nunca va a entrar a las instrucciones declaradas dentro del cuerpo es por eso que **nunca vas a ver en ningun lado** que alguien utilice el While False como tal.

Lo que si es muy comun es utilizar variables que en cierto momento cambien su estado a False para terminar la ejecucion de un While

```
ContinueExecuting = True
while ContinueExecuting:
    #Codigo extra aqui dependiendo de la situacion
    ContinueExecuting = False


print("Execution Finished")
```