# Una explicacion didactica para funciones basicas de Python

Tags: lógica

Soy nueva en Python y no he podido entender a plenitud la lógica de las funciones básicas `while`, `while true`, `for in` y `def`. Alguna idea fácil y didáctica para una persona como yo que requiere de una técnica más didáctica que técnica.
He estado usando estas funciones, pero más a la ciega que siendo consiente de lo que en realidad estoy haciendo.
Gracias de antemano por quien pueda interesarse en mi dificultad.

Comment: No estoy seguro si este tipo de preguntas están permitidas en el sitio. Que es lo que sabes hacer a de cada una de esas sentencias? Que es lo que no te queda claro?

Comment: Hola. Esta pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros, herramientas, librerías de software u otros recursos externos. Para este tipo de consultas existe el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com).
Lo invito verificar  [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic). Tu pregunta debe ser mucho más específica. Esa información abunda en la red, así que debes acudir a [es.so] por una consulta _en particular_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey, comencemos por las funciones, una función es un conjunto de pasos que realizamos de manera repetitiva para optimizar nuestro código, dijéramos que necesitas hacer la cama todos los días, tendrías un código como el siguiente.

```
print("Día lunes:")
print("Sacudir las sabanas")
print("Estirar las sabanas")
print("Acomodar las almohadas")
```

a primera vista no hay tanto problema son algunas líneas de código, pero a medida que agregamos más días se vuelve difícil de mantener

```
print("Día lunes:")
print("Sacudir las sabanas")
print("Estirar las sabanas")
print("Acomodar las almohadas")
print("Día martes: ...")
print("Día miercoles: ...")
```

Así que trabajamos con funciones, usando **def** para declarar nuestras funciones:

```
def hacerLaCama(diaDeLaSemana): # diaDeLaSemana es nuestro parametro(Valor de entrada)
    print(f"Día {diaDeLaSemana}:")
    print("Sacudir las sabanas")
    print("Estirar las sabanas")
    print("Acomodar las almohadas")

hacerLaCama("Lunes") 
hacerLaCama("Martes")
hacerLaCama("Etc ...")
```

Por otra parte si nosotros tuviéramos una lista de días, tendríamos que trabajar con los valores de esa lista y en ese caso podríamos utilizar la instrucción `while`, con la cual **mientras una regla se cumpla realizamos las instrucciones definidas dentro del bloque**.

La sintaxis es la siguiente

```py
while <condicion>:
```

La usamos así:

```
semana = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles"]

def hacerLaCama(diaDeLaSemana):
    print(f"Día {diaDeLaSemana}:")
    print("Sacudir las sabanas")
    print("Estirar las sabanas")

while semana: # Mientras nuestra semana tenga valores ejecutaremos nuestra función 
    hacerLaCama(semana.pop(0)) # pop(0) regresa el valor en curso mientras va eliminando los valores de la lista
```

Una alternativa podria ser utilizar la instruccion `for in` en la cual la variable que declaramos despues de `for` recive el valor en turno y la palabra seguida del `in` es nuestra lista de valores/datos.

Sintaxis:

```py
for <variable> in <iterable>:
```

Uso:

```
semana = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles"]

def hacerLaCama(diaDeLaSemana):
    print(f"Día {diaDeLaSemana}:")
    print("Sacudir las sabanas")
    print("Estirar las sabanas")

for dia in semana:
    hacerLaCama(dia)
```

Y hablando del `while True`, lo usamos cuando utilizas una regla para descartar una caso el cual debe cumplirse mientras sea verdadera, por ejemplo terminar el ciclo cuando la longitud de nuestra lista sea la misma que las veces que imprimimos nuestra funcion.

```
semana = ["Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles","Jueves","Viernes"]

def hacerLaCama(diaDeLaSemana):
    print(f"Día {diaDeLaSemana}:")
    print("Sacudir las sabanas")
    print("Estirar las sabanas")

i = 0 # La variable i es nuestro contador y nos ayuda a recorrer la lista.

while True:
    hacerLaCama(semana[i]) # Llamamos nuestra función con el valor en curso.
    i +=1 # Incrementamos el valor de nuestro contador
    if i == len(semana): # Si nuestro contador y el número de elementos es el mismo terminamos nuestro ciclo.
       break # La instrucción Break rompe el ciclo
```

Al finalizar de ejecutar las instrucciones es dentro del bloque `while` se vuelve al inicio y se ha enteramente la comprobación, si se sigue cumpliendo la condición se vuelve a ejecutar el código.
Para entender más a detalle como funciona el **ciclo While true** te recomiendo la siguiente referencia: [¿Cómo funciona un bucle while True?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142679/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-un-bucle-while-true)

Comment: Podrías usar *f-strngs* para que todo sea más bonito. Haz dicho *pop(0) regresa el valor en curso* lo cual no está de todo mal, e método `pop` retorna e elemento que ha sido borrado  y deberías especificar que se están borrando los elementos. Tu último `while` también se puede mejorar

Comment: Me olvide mencionar que `while semana` no recorre los valores como tu dices, sino que ejecuta ese bloque de código mientras la condición se cumpla, ¿cuál es la condición? Que`semana` sea `True` deberías de poner cual es la sintaxis de cada uno de esos ciclos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus observaciones, ya las estoy agregando, muchas gracias. 

Comment: OK, disculpa si parezco un poco molesto. Tu respuesta me parece buena y estoy tratando de que no halla fallos en la explicación de conceptos, me has ahorrado el tiempo de escribir una :D

Comment: Por el contrario, muchas gracias por el feedback :) está siendo de mucha ayuda. Saludos 

Comment: Voy a realizar una pequeña edición

Comment: Claro, Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias. Super recomendada la respuesta me ayuda muchisimo a tener mas claro que es loq ue hago cuando llamo estas funciones.