# como puedo hacer un bucle infinito en python

Tags: python

quiero que este codigo se siga ejecutando indefinidamnete pero no logro hacerlo soy muy novato

```
import pandas as pd


xl = pd.ExcelFile('./tunuyan/clima.xlsx')
xl.sheet_names
['Column1', 'sheet1']

for tunuyan in xl.sheet_names:
    file = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=tunuyan)
    file.to_csv(tunuyan+'_tunuyan.txt',header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: Envuelvelo todo en un while True. Puedes leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142682/158880 para entender mejor c:

Answer (score 0):

Habría que ver si lo que quieres es que el código cargue una y otra vez el archivo de Excel que estás refiriendo. En ese caso, es tan sencillo como que insertes tu código dentro de un bucle `While` que esté validando `True`, así:

```
import pandas as pd


while True:
    xl = pd.ExcelFile('./tunuyan/clima.xlsx')
    xl.sheet_names
    ['Column1', 'sheet1']

    for tunuyan in xl.sheet_names:
        file = pd.read_excel(xl,sheet_name=tunuyan)
        file.to_csv(tunuyan+'_tunuyan.txt',header=False,index=False)
```

De este modo el código nunca se detendrá, a menos que abortes el proceso o lo detengas desde el Administrador de tareas.

Espero haberte ayudado. Si esperabas otra solución, házmelo saber, por favor