# programa de conversion de digito

Tags: python, python-3.x

soy nuevo usando los lenguajes de programacion, actualmente me han pedido que aprenda Python.

me pidieron un programa para convertir decimal a binario, hexadecimal y octal.

mis preguntas son
¿como hago para que vuelva a inciar el programa? aun no comprendo bien el uso de while, continue.

al arrojar el resultado este ante pone 0b,0o y 0x,¿como oculto estas iniciales?

```
dec = int(input("Introduce un digito: "))
print("El valor decimal de:,", dec, "es:")
print(bin(dec), "en Binario.")
print(oct(dec), "en Octal.")
print(hex(dec), "en hexadecimal.")
```

Comment: Te refieres a que una vez que el usuario ingresó un digito se vuelva a repetir el programa y pregunte el digito de nuevo? Para eso puedes usar un while True, aquí te dejo un link para que puedas entender mejor c: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142682/158880

Comment: Por cierto, lo devuelto por `bin`, `oct` y `hex` es una cadena, para quitar las primeras dos letras de una cadena puedes hacer `cadena[2:]`. También (desde la versión 3.9 de Python) puedes usar [removeprefix](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix)

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. me ayudo mucho.

Comment: De nada Luis Gomez c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pones todo dentro de un `while True:`. Adentro agrega una condición que te permita terminar el ciclo. En este caso, usamos una entrada vacía para señalar el fin del proceso:

```
while True:
    entrada = input("Introduce un digito (Enter para terminar): ")

    if not entrada:
        break

    dec = int(entrada)
    print("El valor decimal de:,", dec, "es:")
    print(bin(dec), "en Binario.")
    print(oct(dec), "en Octal.")
    print(hex(dec), "en hexadecimal.")
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme