# ¿Cómo reemplazar espacios en blanco por letras de la frase?

Tags: python

Me podrían ayudar estoy tratando de hacer que mi código en los espacios que aparece pueda insertar letra de la frase y me vuelva a pedir hasta completar la frase escogida me faltaria implementar un ciclo while pero no se como hacerlo.

```py
    def run():
    frases = ["Vive tu momento",
              "Nunca subestimes el poder de la música",
              "Nunca olvides lo mucho que tu familia te ama",]
    cantidad = len(frases)
    numero= 0
    while numero < 1 or numero > cantidad:
        numero = int(input("Ingrese el numero de frase que desea revelar (1 al {c}): ".format(c=cantidad)))

    frase = frases[numero-1]
    print(frase)
    patron = ""
    for i in frase:
        if i == " ":
            patron += " "
        else:
            patron += "_"
    patron = list(patron)
    print(patron)
    
    letra = input("Ingrese letra: ")
    for i in frase:
       if i.upper() == letra.upper():
           pos = frase.index(i)
           patron[pos] = letra
      
    print(patron)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Por favor, revisa la tabulación en el primer def (así como está, no hace lo que esperas y va a distraer a otros en darte una respuesta)

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta. ¿Esto es como un juego de ahorcado pero con frases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar como guía el hecho de que exista el caracter `_`dentro de `patron`. Tienes otro error en tu código, cuando estás buscando la letra en la frase al usar `.index()` sólo estás sustituyendo la primera aparición:

```
    while '_' in patron:
        letra = input("Ingrese letra: ")
        for i, j in enumerate(frase):
            if j.upper() == letra.upper():
                patron[i] = letra

        print(patron)
```

Lo que consigues de esta manera es que se repita la acción de dentro del bucle `while` siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición de que el string `_` esté contenido dentro de la lista `patron`.

Dado que estás sustituyendo los `_` por la letra correspondiente en esa lista cuando el usuario acierta, llegará un momento en que no queden guiones bajos y se saldrá del bucle. Mientras eso no ocurra seguirá repitiendo la petición de ingresar letra junto con la comprobación

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda me podrías explicar como se esta usando el ciclo while ahí por favor.

Comment: @CarolinaMoran en esta respuesta hay una explicación de como funciona el while y el while True: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142679/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-un-bucle-while-true/142682#142682 Si entiendes esa respuesta, entonces sabrás el proposito de ese while.

Comment: @CarolinaMoran añado a la respuesta una breve explicación del while en este caso