# ¿Que debo hacer para que se repita?-python

Tags: python

contexto:Intente hace un generador de letras de canciones, el problema es que cuando le ofresco la opcion de volver al "menu" no se puede volver a elegir la cancion.El `canciones=(int(input("presione 1")))` lo puse en todas las secciones.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Podrías poner el código como texto por favor? Además de los motivos mencionados en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/158880, piensa que serían pocas personas las que tendrían ganas (o tiempo) de ponerse a transcribir el código de una imagen.

Comment: Respondiendo a tu duda, un [while True](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142681/158880) te solucionaría el problema.

Comment: Un `while Canciones == 1`   también serviría, en caso de que seas fan de la programación estructurada y/o tengas pánico a los `break`. Cualquiera sea la opción que elijas, deberías quitar el último if y su cuerpo.

Answer (score 0):

También soy nuevo en python y hace poco hice un cancionero probando algunas funciones nuevas como implementar diccionarios con índices y fstrings. Lo primero que te recomiendo es que copies tu código como texto y no como imagen para que podamos darte una mejor ayuda. Te voy a pasar mi código así puedas copiar de el lo que te resulte útil.
Nota: Como verás no tengo copiadas las letras de las canciones en si porque pensaba importarlas desde archivos *.txt (y al final no lo terminé y me puse a hacer otros proyectos), pero quiero que te fijes en el código en sí ya que logré resolver el asunto de volver a la selección de canciones que es lo que necesitas, espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos desde Santiago del Estero, Argentina!

```
artistas = {
   "1":"Peteco Carabajal",
   "2":"Vislumbre del Esteko",
   "3":"Presagio"}
cancionesPeteco = {
   "1":"Camino al Amor",
   "2":"Zamba para un Bohemio Guitarrero"}
cancionesVislumbre = {
   "1":"Ckeshu Sisa",
   "2":"Zamba del Llanural"}
cancionesPresagio = {
   "1":"Alma Maternal",
   "2":"Zamba de mi Universo"}

def eligeArtista():
   print (f"""Artistas disponibles:
   1 - {artistas["1"]}
   2 - {artistas["2"]}
   3 - {artistas["3"]}""")
   global numArtista
   numArtista=input("Escribe el numero del artista del cual deseas ver las canciones disponibles: ")
   
def eligeCancion(*args):
   if numArtista == "1":
       print(f"""\nCanciones disponibles:
   1 - {cancionesPeteco["1"]}
   2 - {cancionesPeteco["2"]}""")
   elif numArtista == "2":
       print(f"""\nCanciones disponibles:
   1 - {cancionesVislumbre["1"]}
   2 - {cancionesVislumbre["2"]}""")
   elif numArtista == "3":
       print(f"""\nCanciones disponibles:
   1 - {cancionesPresagio["1"]}
   2 - {cancionesPresagio["2"]}""")
   global numCancion
   numCancion=input("Escribe el numero de la cancion de la cual deseas ver la letra: ")

def muestraLetra(*args):
   if numArtista == "1" and numCancion == "1":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesPeteco["1"]}:""")
   elif numArtista == "1" and numCancion == "2":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesPeteco["2"]}:""")
   elif numArtista == "2" and numCancion == "1":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesVislumbre["1"]}:""")
   elif numArtista == "2" and numCancion == "2":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesVislumbre["2"]}:""")
   elif numArtista == "3" and numCancion == "1":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesPresagio["2"]}:""")
   elif numArtista == "3" and numCancion == "2":
       print (f"""\nLetra de {cancionesPresagio["2"]}:""")
   salida = input("\nPresione Enter para volver a la seleccion de Artistas:\n")
   if salida:
       main()

def main():
   eligeArtista()
   eligeCancion()
   muestraLetra()
   main()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no te sirve mi código en la respuesta anterior, puedo darte una alternativa más fácil, prueba con añadir una variable de control, por ejemplo
`varControl = 1` o `varControl = True`, al inicio de tu código puedes colocar un  `while varControl:` y el ciclo se va a repetir hasta que decidas cambiar el valor de la variable a 0 (o False), por ejemplo con:

```
salida = input('Escriba "salir", para terminar o presione Enter para continuar' )
if salida == "salir"
   varControl = 0
```

O en su caso:

```
salida = input('Escriba "salir", para terminar o presione Enter para continuar' )
if salida == "salir"
   break
```

Comment: En mi opinión esto vendría mejor como una edición a la respuesta original. Ya que añade información a la respuesta que diste antes. Es mas, el sistema debería de haberte dicho "Estas seguro de dar otra respuesta?" y te propone 2 alternativas (una es editar la original)

Comment: Hola @DanteS., si supongo que tienes razón. Aún soy nuevo en estas páginas y es un poco difícil acomodarse a todas las reglas de publicaciones de comentarios, preguntas y respuestas. La gente a veces se pone muy quisquillosa aún cuando se intenta ayudar a otras personas. Voy a rezar para que mis 2 respuestas no causen angustia a nadie ni el incorrecto funcionamiento de la página. Saludos

Comment: Hola! Te entiendo, incluso yo aun no entiendo las reglas al 100%. En ese sentido tranquilisate, no creo que causes angustia a nadie con tus respuestas c: Todo es por mantener la calidad del sitio.