# ¿Es esto código spaghetti?

Tags: python, programación-funcional

soy nuevo en esto de la programación y estoy intentando desarrollar un script sencillo que calcule el IMC de una persona, actualmente esta funcionando tal y como quiero que lo haga, pero se me hacen demasiadas líneas de código para una cosa tan simple, lo que mas me preocupa es que la variable "pregunta" se repite 2 veces, una fuera del bucle While y otra dentro, no sé si esto es una buena práctica o si por el contrario... duelen los ojos a los programadores más experimentados.

Dejo el código por aquí

```
def calculoIMC():

print("Programa que calcula el IMC")
print("---------------------------")

altura = float(input("Por favor, introduzca su altura en cm: "))
altura = altura / 100
peso = float(input("Por favor, introduza su peso en Kg: "))
imc = peso / (altura*altura)

if (imc <= 20):
    print("Su IMC es de: " + str(imc) + " lo que equivale a delgadez")
elif (imc >= 20 and imc <= 25):
    print("Su IMC es de: " + str(imc) + " lo que equivale a un IMC normal")
elif (imc >=26 and imc <= 30):
    print("Su IMC es de: " + str(imc) + " lo que equivale a sobrepeso")
else:
    print("Su IMC es de: " + str(imc) + " lo que equivale a obesidad")

def pedirIMC():
pregunta = int(input("Para calcular su IMC, por favor, pulse 1, en caso contrario pulse 
cualquier tecla: "))
while (pregunta == 1):
    calculoIMC()
    pregunta = int(input("Para calcular su IMC, por favor, pulse 1, en caso contrario pulse 
    cualquier tecla: "))
    if (pregunta == 1):
        continue
    else:
        break

    pedirIMC()
```

Comment: No veo muchos cambios que pueda hacerle al código para que tenga menos lineas. Sin embargo, creo que podría mejorarse. De cualquier modo, si te animas a escribir en ingles, hay un sitio más adecuado para este tipo de dudas: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No necesitas inicializar dos veces la variable pregunta, puedes usar un [while True](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/142682/158880) y romper dicho bucle con break (tal y como lo estás haciendo) cuando pregunta no es igual a 1.

Comment: Revisa cuando IMC = 25.5

Comment: Puedes hacer un do while, donde while es la condición que tienes, pregunta==1, eso te ahorra tener que escribir tu variable pregunta 2 veces, la inicializas 1 vez, y como es un do while, la primera vez siempre va a entrar, y repetirá ese bucle hasta que la pregunta tenga un valor distinto a 1.

Comment: @JuanJesús no existe nada similar en Python

Comment: Para hacer spaghettis necesitas salsa GOTO. Python no tiene ese ingrediente; no puedes hacer spaghettis.

Comment: Sí, acabo de ver que no existe ese bucle en python ,fallo mío. Gracias por la aclaración @DanteS.

Comment: De nada Juan c:

Answer (score 2):

Haciendo refactorización:

```
print("Programa que calcula el IMC")
print("---------------------------")

while True:
    altura = int(input("Por favor, introduzca su altura en cm (o cero para terminar): ")) / 100
    if altura:
        peso = int(input("Por favor, introduza su peso en Kg: "))
        imc = int(peso / (altura * altura))
        if imc <= 20:
            diag = "delgadez"
        elif imc <= 25:
            diag = "normal"
        elif imc <= 30:
            diag = "sobrepeso"
        else:
            diag = "obesidad"

        print(f"Su IMC es de: {imc} lo que equivale a {diag}")
    else:
        break
```

En general las funciones deben recibir parámetros y devolver resultados. Las originales no reciben parámetros; los piden por pantalla y no devuelven resultados; modifican variables globales.

Lo primero es malo, pues mezcla la adquisición con el proceso de los datos. O sea, no puedes reutilizar la función para calcular el IMC a partir de los datos de un archivo, por ejemplo, porque siempre los pedirá por teclado.

En vista y considerando, elimine las funciones y puse todo el código en el `main`.

Las comparaciones del IMC se pueden simplificar; no necesitas chequear el límite inferior, pues eso ya lo hizo el `if/elsif` anterior.

Para "adelgazar" el código elimine los múltiples `print` según el IMC y deje un sólo `print` con parámetros al final.

produce:

```
Programa que calcula el IMC
---------------------------
Por favor, introduzca su altura en cm (o cero para terminar): 184
Por favor, introduza su peso en Kg: 100
Su IMC es de: 29 lo que equivale a sobrepeso
Por favor, introduzca su altura en cm (o cero para terminar):
```